# Europa Universalis Dutch Republic Event

Tags: europa-universalis-iv

What is the event id for the Dutch republic to change your government to a Dutch Republic. When playing as Burgundy, I formed the Netherlands and it kept it to Burgundy's government.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you means this one, #3502?

```
Constitutionalism and the General Estates
country_event = {
    id = flavor_hol.3502
    title = "flavor_hol.EVTNAME3502"
    desc = "flavor_hol.EVTDESC3502"
    picture = ELECTION_REPUBLICAN_eventPicture

    fire_only_once = yes

    trigger = {
        OR = {
            AND = {
                tag = HOL
                NOT = { exists = NED }
            }
            tag = NED
        }
        is_year = 1580
        NOT = { is_year = 1621 }
        NOT = {
            government = dutch_republic
        }
    }

    mean_time_to_happen = {
        months = 200
    }

    option = {
        name = "flavor_hol.EVTOPTA3502" #Confederacy with traces of Monarchism
        change_government = dutch_republic
    }
    option = {
        name = "flavor_hol.EVTOPTB3502" #Confederacy on Republican Model
        change_government = administrative_republic
    }
    option = {
        name = "flavor_hol.EVTOPTC3502" #Centralized Monarchy
        change_government = monarchy
    }
}
```

- There's no condition other than the date to be within the ranges 1580
  to 1620
- Mean time to happen has no modifier, therefore 0.5% chance per month
- Probability of occurrence after n months is p=100%-(100%-0.5%)^n
- Probability for it to trigger over any given play through (40y = 480
  months) si ~91%